# JsPDF, Html2Canvas for loop keeps adding same image

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, jspdf

i'm currently trying to make a Canvas of a lot of Html tables to store them in a PDF file.

I'm doing a ForEach loop to make a canvas of and when it's about to finish i save and download the pdf document.

The problem is that when i download the pdf it shows me the first image in every page.

If for example i have 5 tables in my document, the pdf comes up with 5 pages but every page displays the first canvas created, it doesn't add the newer ones.

Let me show you my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//This is the array i use to store base64 of each element
var PdfImages = [{'base':null}];
PdfImages.splice(0,1);

function ToPDF(){
    $("#someContainer").css("background","#fff");
 //AgregarTabla is another object array i have to store the id's of every
 //table i previously created in html

    $.each(AgregarTabla,function(i){
        var elem = $("#a"+AgregarTabla[i].GrupoID);

        html2canvas(elem,{
            onrendered: function(canvas){
                var data = canvas.toDataURL("img/jpeg");
                PdfImages.push({'base':data});
                doc.addImage(data,"jpeg",0,0,0,0,'Octonyan');   
                doc.addPage();

                data = null;

                if(i == AgregarTabla.length-1){
                    doc.save("test.pdf");
                }
            }
        });//Fin canvas
    });


}

</script>
```

if i use window.open(data) it opens up a new tab with the new image, and every tab shows me the different canvas i created based in the tables of my html.
But when the PDF document is downloaded it always shows me the first canvas i created in every page.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7pVG.png)

Comment: The inner code is async and won't run until .each() has finished which means elem will reference the same element. You need to break up the code so that either proper reference is kept to each element, or do it in chain, one element - produce page - continue to next.

Comment: Thanks K3n, that's pretty helpful. But i'm kind of new with Sync and Async functions so i'm unable to figure out how can i achieve the desired effect.

Is there any example you can provide me to help me? Would a "for loop" help me in any way?

Comment: I added a couple of examples - disclaimer: untested as I don't have test files readily available at the moment, but I think you'll get the gist.

Comment: I'll check them out, much thanks :)